# auto width any element using input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an iframe size generator where if they type a number from the input tag with the minimum width of 300px to 600px only. If a user types a number, it should be change syncronize with the iframe's width size

here's my HTML code

```
<div class="ecp">
    <div class="e">
        <div class="pi-b1">
            <div class="pi-b2">
                <div class="pi-b3">
                    <div class="pi-b4 iframe">
                        <iframe src="https://rarefrostbites.pages.dev/store/com.rarefrostbites.8.1st_century.html" id="iframe" title="1st Century - RareFrostbites Team | RFB Store" loading="lazy" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pi-b1">
            <div class="pi-b2">
                <div class="pi-b3">
                    <div class="pi-b4 controller">
                        <div class="opt">
                            <div class="width">
                                <h4>width</h4>
                                <input type="number" name="width" value="320" min="300" max="600" id="e_width">
                            </div>
                            <div class="height">
                                <h4>height</h4>
                                <input type="number" name="height" value="400" min="400" max="800" id="e_height">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn">
                            <button>
                                <img src="https://rarefrostbites.pages.dev/media/store/assets/icons/gray/Close.svg" class="f" alt="Icon image">
                                <img src="https://rarefrostbites.pages.dev/media/store/assets/icons/white/Close.svg" class="hidden" alt="Icon image">
                            </button>
                            <button>
                                <img src="https://rarefrostbites.pages.dev/media/store/assets/icons/gray/Share.svg" class="f" alt="Icon image">
                                <img src="https://rarefrostbites.pages.dev/media/store/assets/icons/white/Share.svg" class="hidden" alt="Icon image">
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the iframe is what I want to change the size based on the input tag and the .opt is where user controls it

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I searched for tutorials but the results are scammy, it was about auto with of "input" tag, not any element

Comment: You are saying that you have no idea how to write JavaScript that might do that?